# Using Facebook username as a simple universal sign in mechanism

Tags: facebook

Is there a setting in facebook where by I can simply use the facebook username as my universal sign in on sites that accept facebook credentials WITHOUT share any other information between the two websites.

I do want any other sharing of information apart from identity. I dont want facebook to know or paste on my wall what I am doing on other sites. I just want the ease of an already created account to sign in without having to fill forms for a new account on the new site.

Answer (score 2):

Ability to use **Facebook Connect** (Facebook's method of providing registering/log in functionality using Facebook's profile to other websites) is *dependent on those websites actually implementing this technology*. If they do, then you can use it.

See more info at: http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=730